# 2000s cartoon set in a magical boarding school, including a girl with a spider headband and a regular kid who got newly admitted

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

The main cast were 3 characters:

- a girl with a spider hairband and possibly purple hair,
- a snarky blonde guy with a green jacket (I think)
- and a regular kid.

The series was set in a magical boarding school and the regular kid was a new admission.

Comment: Oof, that's really really broad and unanswerable with the current level of details (too many possible matches). Please [edit] in more specific info. You say there's a magic school. Do kids specialise, for instance the girl has Fire powers and the blonde guy Earth powers? What did the villains do, if there even were villains? What's Regular Kid doing at a magic school to begin with? As well as any other memories you could think of by reading [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028).

Comment: Understood, I'll try.

Comment: Was regular kid a boy or girl?

Comment: @Jenayah - Not at all unanswerable. It could certainly do with more detail, but there are some nice unique features like the girl's spider headgear.

Comment: "Pretty old" hahahahaha! :)

Answer (score 9):

Could this be *[Ultimate Book of Spells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Book_of_Spells)* (2001)? The main characters include Cassandra, a young witch with a distinctive spider headband and *blue* hair but a *purple* dress, which is probably what you're recalling. The other characters include Gus (blond hair, green jacket) and a mortal boy, Verne, who serves as the '[everyman](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheEveryman)' character.

The whole thing is set in a magical school.

[image: girl with spider headband and blonde guy in a green jacket, both riding some kind of bike]

Comment: If accepted, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80341/identify-an-animated-tv-series-which-was-copy-of-harry-potter/80344#80344 FWIW

Answer (score 0):

Could it be Creepschool? I was just looking for the answer too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the ways in which this matches the cartoon described in the question, and any ways in which it doesn't. Specifying the year in which this originally aired would be helpful too.